# tkinter button animation stuck after using wait_window()

Tags: python, user-interface, events, tkinter, dialog

This is a dialog form class :

** update full workable source code showing the problem

```
from tkinter import *
class SGForm:
    created_form = False
    def __init__(self, root, title=""):
        self.form = Toplevel(root)
        self.form.wm_title(title)
        self.input = dict()
        self.var = StringVar()
        SGForm.created_form = True

    def getform(self):
        return self.form

    def addinput(self, name, text ,var = None):
        p = Frame(self.form)
        p.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        l = Label(p, text=text)
        l.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.input[name] = Entry(p, textvariable=var)
        self.input[name].pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

    def addbutton(self, text, signal, func):
        p = Frame(self.form)
        p.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        b = Button(p, text=text)
        b.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        b.bind(signal, func)

    def showandreturn(self):
        value = dict()
        value['firstname'] = self.var.get()
        SGForm.created_form = False
        return value

    def closeform(self, event):
        self.form.destroy()

    def customform(self):
        self.addinput('entfirstname', 'frist name', self.var)
        self.addbutton('close','<Button-1>', self.closeform)

#example calling dialog class
root = Tk()

def evntshow(event):
    form = SGForm(root)
    form.customform()
    root.wait_window(form.getform())
    test = form.showandreturn()
    print(test)
button = Button(root, text='show')
button.pack()
button.bind('<Button-1>', evntshow)
root.mainloop()
```

Each time the button get pressed `eventaddperson` get triggered, when exiting the function the button animation of the main window get stuck on press status, I am looking for a way to refresh the gui or what if I am doing something wrong how to fix it?

Comment: did you try `update()` main window before `wait_window()` ? `wait_window()` runs mainloop only for form so mainloop can't change buttons in main windows. `update()` should force mainloop to change buttons in main window.

Comment: I just tried it and didn't work.

Comment: you will have to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we could run it - and maybe you will find problem when you will create example.

Comment: BTW: `Buttton` has `command=` to assign function - `Button( ..., command= evntshow)` - and you don't have to use `bind('<Button-1>', evntshow)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use `command=` instead of `bind()` then problem disappers

BTW: if you use `command=` then `def evntshow()`has to be without `event`

```
def evntshow(): # <--- without event
    form = SGForm(root)
    form.customform()
    root.wait_window(form.getform())
    test = form.showandreturn()
    print(test)

# use `command=` instead of `bind('<Button-1>',...)
button = Button(root, text='show', command=evntshow)
button.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing kind of laggy button animations when using bind() as well, switching to command= made it a look a lot better!

```
from tkinter import * 
import time 

def func1():
    print('waiting for 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)

def func2(event):
    print('waiting for 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)

root = Tk()
# button animation runs smoothly
Button1 = Button(root, text="button with command=", command=func1) 
Button1.pack()

Button2 = Button(root, text="button with bind()") # button animation does not occur
Button2.bind('<Button-1>', func2)
Button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I am working with python 3.6 and windows 10

Comment: Please provide one working sample codes as your descriptions.

Comment: @Sphinx Ty! please run this snippet to see what I mean